# web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log) Error

Tags: web3js, blockchain, dapps

Can you please help me with this error ! How to fix this ??

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log)
```

> TypeError: this.provider.sendAsync is not a function
>       at RequestManager.sendAsync (/home/chaitanyarajeev/ethereum_voting_dapp/chapter1/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:80:19)
>       at Eth.get [as getAccounts] (/home/chaitanyarajeev/ethereum_voting_dapp/chapter1/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/property.js:116:33)

Comment: Add the source code so we can take a look..

Comment: web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log)
TypeError: this.provider.sendAsync is not a function
    at RequestManager.sendAsync (/home/chaitanyarajeev/ethereum_voting_dapp/chapter1/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:80:19)
    at Eth.get [as getAccounts] (/home/chaitanyarajeev/ethereum_voting_dapp/chapter1/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/property.js:116:33)
>

Comment: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/callbacks-promises-events.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts( (error, accounts) => { ... } )
```